# Search Refiners with spaces causes error

Tags: 2013, development, search, csom

So I've been looking at CSOM searching in sharepoint 2013.
The old way with scopes and the webservice no longer seems to be an option.

So I've cracked out the KeywordQuery object which seems to be Microsofts intent.
It seems better and easier to use.

My code is thus.

```
    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(this);
    keywordQuery.QueryText = searchTerm;

    var properties = keywordQuery.SelectProperties;
    keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;


    properties.Add("ListID");
    properties.Add("ListItemID");

    keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add("Forename:string(\"" + forename.Trim() + "\",mode = 'any')");

    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(this);

    var results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
    this.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now this seems to be fine if the `forename` has no spaces. The moment that it has spaces this causes errors. What gives? 
Can I escape the spaces or other characters? What is the process here?

My error is

```
Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, been around this and the basics are that you can use FQL in the keywordQuery.
You need to do your search like this.

```
keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add("Forename:string('" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(forename.Trim()) + "')");
```

So encode it.

here is a snippet for 'or'

```
var businessUnitSql = "";
                    foreach (var bu in businessUnits)
                    {
                        if(businessUnitSql != "")
                        {
                            businessUnitSql = businessUnitSql + ",";
                        }

                        businessUnitSql = businessUnitSql + "BusinessUnit:'" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(bu) + "'";


                    }

                    if (businessUnits.Count() > 1)
                    {

                        businessUnitSql = "or(" + businessUnitSql + ")";

                    }

                    keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add(businessUnitSql);
```

Got there in the end.